# Magento under version control

Tags: svn, magento

I've experimented with keeping Magento under SVN for a few projects now, I've been using the following ignore list.

**svn:ignore**

media/catalog/product/cache
media/css
media/css_secure
media/js
includes (yes I will have to run compilation every time a there is a new release)
var

Now... My problem is that when you clear the image/css/js caches using cache management Magento also deletes the hidden .svn folders, this causes a 'missing' conflict. Is there any way around this? or easy way to resolve the issue?

I need to have the live release under version control so I can keep the client uploaded media files synced with the repository.

Comment: add the cache folder to the ignore list

Comment: I have media/css, media/js and media/css_secure in the ignore list but they still contain a .svn folder which is deleted by Magento

Comment: haha, if only that was an option

Comment: Do you use Magento with Git? What are the benefits?

Comment: Well, try to export, not update?

Comment: GIT has many benefits when working with Magento, e.g. speed (merge a complete Magento upgrade in seconds), no .svn directories everywhere (which is nice because of Magento's many folders), easy ignore list management. There are more but thats too much for a single comment.

Comment: i just new to svn, can i get complete docs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `cache` directory from the repository (can be done using `svn rm [REPO_URL]/media/catalog/product/cache` command) and the problem is gone. But note that you would still need to keep this dir under **svn:ignore**.

Comment: Thanks, I had just assigned svn:ignore to each individual dir now I've put the ignore params on the media dir instead. Works fine.